# Why is different result using strtok_r in Mac & Ubuntu

Tags: c, strtok

I'm practice c Lang strtok_r().
Here is my code.

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    char* ptr = NULL;
    char* next[2] = {0};
    char delimiter[4];
    int now = 1;

    strcpy(delimiter, " \t");

    // check argc number
    if(argc != 3){
        printf("usage : ./test {string} {string}\n");
        return -1;
    }

    ptr = strtok_r(argv[1], delimiter, &next[1]); 
    printf("ptr : %s, next : %s\n", ptr, next[1]);
    
    ptr = strtok_r(argv[2], delimiter, &next[2]); 

    while((ptr = strtok_r(NULL, delimiter, &next[1])) != NULL){
        printf("%d : %s, next : %s\n", ++now, ptr, next[1]);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

I think that code result will be

```sh
$ a.out "I'm test now" "Hello every"
ptr : i'm, next : test now
2 : test, next : now
3 : now, next : (null)
```

My mac result is that.

But my ubuntu20.04(Docker image) isn't.
Here is result of execute on Ubuntu.

```sh
$ a.out "i'm test now" "hello every"
ptr : i'm, next : test now
2 : test now, next :
```

Why result is different in Mac & ubuntu

Comment: `&next[2]` is UB. Perhaps indices 0 and 1 should be used instead..

Comment: Umm.... I fixed code 1->0, 2->1. It works well. But I think first "strtok_r" use "next[1] ". First "strtok_r" must be  work well regardless of  second "strtok_r" have problem. Isn't it..?

Comment: Not quite sure what that means. Anyway, use a debugger and inspect the value of `delimiter` *after* the second call to strtok when using `&next[2]`, as in the original code. I have a suspicion it is changing the value to garbage — the array only has 2 elements and changing the invalid/non-existing 3rd element (UB) appears to be overwriting important data. Search for “*buffer overflow*”. Removing the strtok call using `&next[2]` should also fix the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think that problem related to memory like "buffer overflow" :)

Comment: OT: regarding: `printf("usage : ./test {string} {string}\n");`   Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.   Suggest: `fprintf( stderr, "usage :  %s {string} {string}\n", argv[0] );`  Note: an executable can be executed under any name, simply by renaming it.   The `argv[0]` always contains the name of the executable.

Comment: Print error message into 'stderr' is a rule in c language? I think that program not end abnormal. So that program can print error message use 'printf'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

regarding:

```
char* next[2] = {0};
...
ptr = strtok_r(argv[1], delimiter, &next[1]); 
printf("ptr : %s, next : %s\n", ptr, next[1]);

ptr = strtok_r(argv[2], delimiter, &next[2]); 

while((ptr = strtok_r(NULL, delimiter, &next[1])) != NULL){
```

the array: `next` has 2 elements.  Therefore, the valid indexes into that array are 0 and 1.  Not 1 and 2.

The posted code is accessing beyond the end of the `next` array.  The result is Undefined Behavior.

Note:  the valid indexes into an array are 0...(number of elements in array -1)

Comment: Yes, I used not defined element index. But I think that strtok using 'next[1]' should be working well.. May be because of accessing beyond the end of 'next' array it works undefined behavior! Thank you :)