# When allocating automatic variables to stack, does the compiler group them by size and then allocate contiguous locations?

Tags: c, variables, gcc, stack, memory-address

I wrote a simple program to understand this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
        int i = 3, *x;
        char j = 'c', *y;
        int k = 1, *z;
        x = &i;
        y = &j;
        z = &k;
        fprintf(stdout, "Address in x = %p\n", x);
        fprintf(stdout, "Address in y = %p\n", y);
        fprintf(stdout, "Address in z = %p\n", z);
        fprintf(stdout, "Subtracting x from z = %li\n", z - x);
        return 0;
}
```

I ran this program multiple times, and always got output which was similar in nature:

```
Address in x = 0x7ffd7e981348
Address in y = 0x7ffd7e981347
Address in z = 0x7ffd7e98134c
Subtracting x from z = 1
```

...Although, the source code defines the `char j` in between the two `ints i and k`; `i` and `k` were always allocated contiguous memory locations i.e., `4 bytes` or `1 * sizeof(int)` apart, for my system-compiler combo. I would assume that the compiler is grouping by `type` and allocating them contiguous memory locations for their type. However, changing the source code and adding a `float` to the mix like thus...

```
int main(void)
{
        int i = 3, *w;
        char j = 'c', *x;
        float k = 3.145, *y;
        int l = 1, *z;
        w = &i;
        x = &j;
        y = &k;
        z = &l;
        fprintf(stdout, "Address of i = %p\n", w);
        fprintf(stdout, "Address of j = %p\n", x);
        fprintf(stdout, "Address of k = %p\n", y);
        fprintf(stdout, "Address of l = %p\n", z);
        fprintf(stdout, "Subtracting w from z = %li\n", z - w);
        return 0;
}
```

outputs...

```
Address of i = 0x7ffe256f04cc
Address of j = 0x7ffe256f04cb
Address of k = 0x7ffe256f04d0
Address of l = 0x7ffe256f04d4
Subtracting w from z = 2
```

...Ergo, the compiler isn't grouping by `type` but `size`. So, my questions are

1. Do all compilers always group together variables with the same size and then allocate them contiguous memory locations on the stack?
2. Does this happen for all storage classes and variable/constants stored in other memory segments, too?
3. Why is this done? Is this some kind of optimization? If yes, how exactly does it "optimize" stuff?

TIA!

Comment: Without taking the addresses, the variables might not “exist” in memory at all. Taking the address severely limits what the compiler *can* do.

Comment: This is not specified by the standard, and you are not supposed to care. Each compiler will do it as it sees fit, and can do it differently depending on the optimization level.

Comment: Without taking the address, the variables *could* be optimized to registers only, or even elided to direct values in cases they are effectively constants etc.

Comment: @user2864740 that would be when I assign storage class register, yes?

Comment: The compiler can optimize as it sees fit, so long as this does not violate the C language. Taking the addresses eliminates such optimizations as it imposes another requirement.

Comment: [Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64290928/2864740) (not a duplicate/related question), of two different builds that produce different output *on Undefined Behavior*, due to having different layouts and/or optimizations. UB that “works” in one build and fails on another is relatively common due to differing (and equally valid) compilation differences.

Comment: `z - w` This is no legal code. You are not allowed to do pointer arithmetics with pointers that do not point to the same memory object. `i` and `k` are not the same object. there is a gap in between them that does is not a multiple of `sizeof int` what value would you expect to get?

Comment: umm... @Gerhardh I get your point on UB. But where do you see the "*..gap in between them that is not a multiple of `sizeof int`...*" in the reprex I have shared?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "reprex".There are architectures that do not require any alignment. With `char j` in between `z` and `w` the address difference can be an odd number which cannot be represented as "multiple of type where `z` points to"

Answer (score 0):

You can see disassembly code. that is help your question.

Firstly, Function allocate to empty space and allocate value size
If you create 3 values(x, y, z). So, In disassembly like that.

```c
// create new 3 values
int x = 0
int y = 1
int z = 2

// To assembly
PUSH EBP
MOV ESP, EBP
SUB ESP, 0x0C
MOV [EBP-4], 0
MOV [EBP-8], 1
MOV [EBP-C], 2
```

It show you, Why memory allocated continuous space.

And then optimization different each compiler. Like sometimes it delete const value And it make different calling convention.

Answer (score -1):

> When allocating (auto) variables to stack, does the compiler group by size and allocate them contiguous locations?

Read the C11 standard [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).

#### The compiler is allowed to reorder the location of [automatic variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable) on the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack), or to [optimize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) to the point of just keeping them in [processor registers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_register).

A clever enough compiler might compute `w = &i;` at compile time (but be in practice aware of [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization)). Other compilers might do some [inline expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion). Read the [Dragon book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools) and recent papers accepted to [PLDI](https://conf.researchr.org/home/pldi-2020) conferences or to ACM [SIGPLAN](https://www.sigplan.org/).

Try also [cross-compiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler) your C code for [Arduino](https://www.arduino.cc/). You might have surprises.

IIRC, some past versions of [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) had an optimization pass doing (in simple enough cases) some reordering of automatic variables. Be however aware of [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem).

If you use a recent GCC (in October 2020, that means [GCC 10](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/)), try compiling your `example.c` code with `gcc -O3 -fverbose-asm -S -Wall -Wextra example.c` then look into the emitted `example.s` assembler code.

Read [this draft](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/bismon-chariot-doc.pdf) report (funded by [CHARIOT](https://www.chariotproject.eu/) and [DECODER](http://decoder-project.eu/) H2020 projects) and look into the [MILEPOST GCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MILEPOST_GCC) and [CTuning](https://ctuning.org/) projects

Try also using [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/) and the [Clang tidy static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) on your C code. Read [documentation of GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/), notably the chapter about [Invoking GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html), and the section about [Static Analyzer Options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Static-Analyzer-Options.html).

You could **consider studying the [source code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source) of open source C compilers** such as [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/), [tinycc](https://github.com/TinyCC/tinycc), or [nwcc](http://nwcc.sourceforge.net/). You could also look inside the [CompCert](http://compcert.inria.fr/) project.

You could **consider writing your own [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) to reorganize local variables** (budget more than a full year of work). Then please write a conference paper about it. You could get a PhD out of such a work.

> If yes, how exactly does it "optimize" stuff?

Read more about [abstract interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_interpretation) techniques and [Robinson arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson_arithmetic) applied to [whole program optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interprocedural_optimization). Many compilers use some of them, and your GCC plugin would probably use them too (perhaps by coupling it to some [proof assistant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_assistant), like in 2021 [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/)).